# Randomly disconnecting from MongoDB. Using MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb

im having this weird problem. It just randomly im getting disconnected to MongoDB from my NodeJS server. This happens when i try to change something on the angular side or server code, it doesn't always disconnect, it's just sometimes.

[image]

do any of you experience this problem? thank you!

Comment: When you "change something on the server code", are you blocking the NodeJS thread temporarily (e.g. pausing on a break point)? This could block interactions with MongoDB.

Comment: Have you looked in the mongodb server log?